# MYSQL, how to get rows with field value of 'x' in this case?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to query a mysql db.

After the query, I am using mysql_fetch_array in a while loop to display all results inside a table.

Now, depending on a variable ($adtypes) I want the query-results-array to change...

Explanation: ($query_results is the name of the array containing the query results, 
basically something like `SELECT * FROM table` so it selects everything!

```
$adtypes = $_GET['adtypes'];
//$adtypes is irrelevant to query, the query is already done before all this.
switch ($adtypes){
case "Private":
$query_results = //Here I want the array to only contain values where the mysql row field = 'Private'
    break;
    case "company":
    $query_results = // Same thing as above, but only company ads
    break;
    }
```

Then I do a loop through the array to display the results like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_results)){
```

How can I make sure the array (query_results) only contain the info I want WITHOUT doing another query ?

Thanks

If you need more input, tell me and I will update this Q.

**UPDATE**

I cannot have another query, because my queries are very large, and they DO affect performance in a negative way.

I Think a foreach is what I am after...

Also, the reason I cant manipulate the current query is because I am displaying the nr of private ads and nr of company ads on my site, and all that info comes from the query.

So, if I query my db where I only search for private ads, then I cant display how many company ads there where ( IF i dont do another query )!

Thanks anyways guys...

Comment: Let's take it as given that you can't make another query (feel free to explain this ;-)).
Can you at least change the while-loop to e.g. a foreach-loop? Or is this switch statement the only plcae where you can (or want) to make changes?

Comment: Ok, it is "doable". But then you have to perform the filter operations in php without the help of any index mysql could use. If it really is only a simple `field=x` to determine the number of rows another mysql query should beat the php implementation in any case (since this is an info that can be obtained directly from the index without touching the actual data). Do you have a proper index for `field='Private'`? In case of doubt `EXPLAIN SELECT ... WHERE filed='Private'` can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'Private'
```

no need to use php for this. but if you really need to, you could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$query_result = array_filter($query_result, create_function('$var', 'return $var['field'] != \'Private\''));
```

**edit:** as stated in the comments, to get the number of private and company ads, use mysql’s `COUNT`:

```
  SELECT `adtype`, COUNT(*) as `nr_of_ads`
    FROM `ads`
GROUP BY `adtype`
```

Comment: As I said, the query is already made, I cant have 2 queries or do a query like this in my case!

Comment: why can't you do another query?

Comment: because it slows things down !

Comment: I don't think this is true. You can get them in one query, and then split them up into two arrays, but you'll have to fiddle with arrays and the performance gain is minimal, if there is any.

Comment: why don't you adapt your first query?

Comment: because I am displaying the nr of private ads, company ads on the page, If I filter the query, the numbers change

Comment: issuing two queries is most of the times faster than filtering the results with PHP, because mysql can use indices if you set them on the right column.

Comment: furthermore, if you want to display the number of ads, i recommend you use the `COUNT` function of mysql. editing my post accordingly

Comment: ok thanks... I will look into this... but we are talking about around 600 thousand ads

Comment: 600 k isn’t too much. just be sure to put an index on your `ad_type` column

Answer (score 1):

It seems questionable that you either can't do another query, or use the filter on the query in the first place; this leads me to think that your design needs to be slightly revisited.

In any case, the value that you pass to `mysql_fetch_array` is a resource identifier; it is pointing to the resource that represents the output of the original query, but it isn't actually the output of the original query. If this is **really** the only query that you can run, and you really want to only have results that contain the `$adtypes` value, then you will need to filter these from the original query results (within the loop on `mysql_fetch_array`). You can't change the resource that `$query_results` is pointing to.